# Simple physics question pls help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

If two balls, A and B are projected with an angle from the same level but both reach same maximum height. The angle that Ball B makes with the horizontal line is greater than the angle that Ball A makes which of them has longer flight time?

A. Ball A
B. Ball B
C. Same flight time

Answer (score 3):

Two questions to ask yourself about this problem:

1. Does the horizontal component of the balls' velocities matter to flight time?
2. What does the fact that the balls reach the same maximum height tell you about their initial vertical velocities?